# Aggregating an object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So, I'm experimenting with AngularJS, and, as an exercise, figured I would make a simple application using the Steam API. I have made a simple Spring Boot Rest service, which provides a reverse proxy service for the Steam API, in such a way that certain calls can be forwarded. At this time there are two actions:

`/user/` provides a list of steam id's.
`/user/:id/games` provides the output of the following api:
http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=MY_STEAM_KEY&steamid=STEAM_ID&format=json

which returns an answer in the following format:

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "game_count":3,
      "games":[  
         {  
            "appid":70000,
            "playtime_forever":0
         },
         {  
            "appid":550,
            "playtime_forever":0
         },
         {  
            "appid":274900,
            "playtime_forever":0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to extract the `games` array from this json object, and append it to the correct user. And I want to do this for all users. I have achieved something close to what I want using the $resource object, by defining the following factories:

```
angular.module("SAM.Resources", [])
    .factory("UserList", ["$resource",
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/user');
        }])

    .factory("GamesList", ["$resource",
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/user/:id/games', {
                id: '@id'
            });
        }
    ]);
```

And then in my controller use the following:

```
UserList.query(function(response){
    $scope.users = response ? response : [];
    for(index=0; index < $scope.users.length; ++index){
        user = $scope.users[index];
        $scope.users[index].games = GamesList.get({id:user.id});
    }
});
```

This is close to what I want, *however*, it returns something of the format:

```
  {
    "id": "76561198119953061",
    "name": "Yuri",
    "games": {
      "response": {
        "game_count": 3,
        "games": [
          {
            "appid": 70000,
            "playtime_forever": 0
          },
          {
            "appid": 550,
            "playtime_forever": 0
          },
          {
            "appid": 274900,
            "playtime_forever": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

And I don't want the `games.response.games` construction. I have tried to change it to:

```
$scope.users[index].games = GamesList.get({id:user.id}).response.games;
```

which fails, seems logical, as it is a promise, and doesn't immediately contain the response object.

I've also tried to use something like

```
GamesList.get({id:user.id}), function(response){
 angular.extend(user, response);
});
```

Which does indeed append the response to the `user` object, only the `user` object is always the last value in the array by the time the promise resolves.

So basically my question comes down to: **How can I extend my `User` object with the `Games` list?**

Comment: _"which fails, seems logical, as it is a promise, and doesn't immediately contain the response object."_ - Except that that code is in the `success` callback. `response` should be filled there...

Comment: @Cerbrus `response` is filled correctly, but `user` is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code around a bit:

```
UserList.query(function(response){
    $scope.users = response ? response : [];
    for(index=0; index < $scope.users.length; ++index){
        user = $scope.users[index];

        (function(index, id){
            GamesList.get({id: id}, function(response){ // Get the games from the response
                $scope.users[index].games = response.response.games;
            }));
        })(index, user.id)
    }
});
```

In the `for` loop, `user` keeps changing value. By the time the first `GameList.get` has a value returned, your loop will be at the last user already.

Wrapping that in an [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) separates those variables in a separate scope.

Comment: Notice that you need to use `response.response.`, since the `response` from the server contains an `response` object that contains the `games`

Comment: Thanks, marked your answer as **the answer**, because of the IIFE.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: nice, clean approach!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(index=0; index < $scope.users.length; ++index){
    user = $scope.users[index];
    $scope.users[index].games = GamesList.get({id:user.id}, function(response){
        angular.extend(user, response);
    }));
}
```

When you do that, the user variable will change at every step. But the anonymous callback will be executed later. So only the last user is used.

You can fix that by using an anonymous function as a scope with `forEach` :

```
$scope.users.forEach(function(user) {
    $scope.users[index].games = GamesList.get({id:user.id}, function(response){
        angular.extend(user, response);
    }));
});
```

If you want to avoid the `user.games.response.games`, you need to merge the objects in a different way.

```
$scope.users.forEach(function(user) {
    $scope.users[index].games = GamesList.get({id:user.id}, function(response){
        user.games = response.games;
        user.games_count = response.games_count;
    }));
});
```

Comment: Ah that at least solves part of my problem, thanks :)! So, how can I make sure the response.games part is removed?

Comment: You can use `delete response.games;` if you want to remove a property from an object.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: After the promise resolves, the object contains something of the format: `user.games.response.games`, which I want to simplify to `user.games`.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks :). It's actually `response.response.games`, but it was clear enough :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I can only mark 1 answer as the correct one, so I gave an  upvote.